# Ajuda em select para trazer campo mesmo que null

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Necessito de ajuda para criação de um select, tenho 4 tabelas (comissão, pessoa, pedido, pedidoitem). Então preciso trazer todas as pessoas e seus valores de metas mesmo que não tenha ainda valores em pedido. fiz um select o problema que ele não retorna a pessoa quando não tem pedido pra essa pessoa.

Quero que ele retorne por exemplo: nome da pessoa/ meta/ valoralcançado

meu código está assim até agora:

```
SELECT
  [PESSOA].[Fantasia] AS PESSOA,
  [METAS].[MetaValorMinimoBase] AS META,
  SUM(ISNULL(PDV_PedidoItemValorTotal,0)) AS Valor


FROM COM_METAS
  FULL JOIN PESSOA ON METAS.MetaRepCod = PESSOA.Codigo
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDO ON PESSOA.Codigo = PEDIDO.PedidoRepresentante
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDOITEM ON PEDIDO.PedidoCodigo = PEDIDOITEM.PedidoCodigo

WHERE PEDIDO.PedidoExcluido = 'N' and
PEDIDO.PedidoTipoMovimentoCodigo IN (1,5,6) AND
PEDIDO.PedidoSituacao IN ('A','B','O','T','E')AND
PEDIDO.PedidoDataEmissao BETWEEN '01/06/2018'  AND '05/06/2018'

GROUP BY
  [PESSOA].[Fantasia],
  [METAS].[MetaValorMinimoBase]

Order by [PESSOA].[Fantasia]
```

**RETORNO :**

```
JOÃO      |60000    |697569
PEDRO     |240000   |1374417
MARIA     |60000    |67995
FRANCISCO |200000   |2376976
ZÉ        |NULL     |23423
ROMARIO   |20000    |NULL
```

Quero que me traga as outras pessoas que tem metas mesmo que não tenha valor.

Ele até retorna as pessoas com meta null, mas quero que retorne também os que tem valor(dos pedidos) null ou 0 no caso.

Comment: Relacionada (duplicada?): [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-é-a-diferença-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448)

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa fazer uso do `LEFT JOIN` ao invés do `INNER JOIN`, assim mesmo que não haja registros na tabela o resultado será listado. Será necessário também reorganizar sua `query` para que a tabela com os dados mais importantes, no seu caso `PESSOA` seja a base da consulta:

```
SELECT pes.EMP_Fantasia AS PESSOA,
       m.COM_MetaValorMinimoBase AS META,
       SUM(ISNULL(pi.PDV_PedidoItemValorTotal, 0)) AS Valor
  FROM dbo.PESSOA pes dbo.PEDIDO p
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDO p ON p.PDV_PedidoRepresentante = pes.EMP_Codigo
  LEFT JOIN dbo.PEDIDOITEM pi ON p.PDV_PedidoCodigo = pi.PDV_PedidoCodigo
  FULL JOIN dbo.METAS ON pes.EMP_Codigo = m.COM_MetaRepCod
 WHERE p.PedidoSituacao IS NULL
    OR (p.PedidoExcluido = 'N'
   AND p.PedidoTipoMovimentoCodigo IN (1,5,6)
   AND p.PedidoSituacao IN ('A','B','O','T','E')
   AND p.PedidoDataEmissao BETWEEN '01/06/2018' AND '05/06/2018')
 GROUP BY p.EMP_Fantasia,
          m.COM_MetaValorMinimoBase
```

Comment: simples, elegante e objetivo; +1

Comment: Olá, primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda!! Tentei esse codigo e já melhorou o resultado mas ainda não é oque preciso, assim preciso que o codigo me traga também as pessoas e meta que não tem pedidos ainda, mas tem cadastro, ou seja seu valor seria 0. Que o codigo assim me traz todas as pessoas e meta que contem pedido. (Não sei se estão me entendendo, qualquer coisa posto mais detalhes) A ideia é me retornar todas as pessoas que tem metas e valores que ja alcançou mesmo que 0.

Comment: @Jona acredito com o `ISNULL` no campo tenhamos o retorno que você gostaria

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usando o `left join`

Veja que foi selecionado as pessoas e é feito um `left join` para que traga mesmo não tendo pedidos, no `sum` também foi adicionado um verificador que caso seja nulo, trará o valor 0

```
SELECT
  [PESSOA].[Fantasia] AS REPRESENTANTE,
  [METAS].[MetaValorMinimoBase] AS META,
  SUM(ISNULL(PDV_PedidoItemValorTotal,0)) AS Valor
FROM COM_METAS
  FULL JOIN PESSOA ON METAS.MetaRepCod = PESSOA.Codigo
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDO ON PESSOA.Codigo = PEDIDO.PedidoRepresentante
  LEFT JOIN PEDIDOITEM ON PEDIDO.PedidoCodigo = PEDIDOITEM.PedidoCodigo
WHERE (1=1)
    AND ISNULL(PEDIDO.PedidoExcluido, 'N') = 'N' 
    AND ISNULL(PEDIDO.PedidoTipoMovimentoCodigo, 1) IN (1,5,6) 
    AND ISNULL(PEDIDO.PedidoSituacao, 'A') IN ('A','B','O','T','E')
    AND ISNULL(PEDIDO.PedidoDataEmissao, ''01/06/2018'') BETWEEN '01/06/2018'  AND '05/06/2018'
GROUP BY
  [PESSOA].[Fantasia],
  [METAS].[MetaValorMinimoBase]
Order by [PESSOA].[Fantasia]
```

Aconselho a leitura de: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448)

Answer (score 0):

## Resolvido!

Retirei o `Where` e fiz a condição direto no `Join` e adicionei um `OR` na junção com a tabela `Pessoa` para me trazer os nomes quando tiver tanto relação com a meta como com o pedido.

```
<pre>SELECT

  PESSOA.Fantasia AS REPRESENTANTE,
  METAS.MetaValorMinimoBase AS META,
  COALESCE(SUM(PEDIDOITEM.PedidoItemValorTotal),0) AS Valor
 
FROM PEDIDO
  INNER JOIN PEDIDOITEM ON PEDIDO.PedidoCodigo = PEDIDOITEM.PedidoCodigo
AND 
PEDIDO.PedidoExcluido = 'N' and
PEDIDO.PedidoTipoMovimentoCodigo IN (1,5,6) AND
PEDIDO.PedidoSituacao IN ('A','B','O','T','E')AND
PEDIDO.PedidoDataEmissao BETWEEN '01/06/2018'  AND '05/06/2018'
  FULL JOIN METAS ON PEDIDO.PedidoRepresentante = METAS.MetaRepCod
  LEFT JOIN PESSOA ON  METAS.MetaRepCod = PESSOA.Codigo or
  PEDIDO.PedidoRepresentante = PESSOA.Codigo



GROUP BY
  PESSOA.Fantasia,
  METAS.MetaValorMinimoBase,

Order by PESSOA.Fantasia</pre>
```